# Melted spark plug on 50cc scooter

Tags: sparkplugs, scooter

I recently adjusted my valves on my wolf v50 scooter. I put a new cdi box new plugs and took off the air filter box and on a cone filter on it. It ran great then all a sudden it just died as i was riding it got it home started to take it apart took the plug out and it completely melted where it sparks. Oh i also changed the magneto flywheel..what woud cause the spark plug to melt like that? Too much air? The cone air filter makes it sound different like a little louder im gonna put the original air box back on.. if anyone has ony ideas what caused that please lmk i dont wanna burn the piston up

Comment: A weak mixture can cause the combustion temperature to rise... did you adjust the valves correctly? Did you check the mixture after changing the filter?

Comment: The spark plug electrodes would not have melted; they are Inconel type alloy or platinum. A very high amperage  , steadty current would be necessary . like a metal melting electric furnace.